# Rails 3 complicated validation design

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, associations

I have a `Contribution` and `Reward` model. A contribution `belongs_to` a reward. I want a contribution to be valid only its amount is greater than its reward's `minimum_contribution`.

So I have

```
Class Contribution < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :reward_id, :reward
  belongs_to :reward

  validates_presence_of :amount
  validates_numericality_of :amount, greater_than: 0
  validates_presence_of :reward

  validates_each :amount, unless: SOMECONDITION do |contribution, attr, amount|
    reward = contribution.reward
    contribution.errors.add(attr,
                            "Contribution must be at least #{reward.minimum_contribution}") unless amount > reward.minimum_contribution
  end
end
```

My question is what is appropriate to put for `SOMECONDITION`. Before this validation is run, I need to make sure that

1. the contribution's valid is defined (or even that it's numeric). Otherwise comparing in `unless value > reward.minimum_contribution` will have an error because you can't compare to nil
2. the contribution's reward is defined
3. the contribution's reward's minimum_contribution is defined and numeric

Should I be doing this ALL in the lambda for `SOMECONDITION`? Something just feels wrong about having so many guards for a single validation. Am I designing this properly? Is it ever proper design to throw an exception in my validation, for instance, `unless amount > contribution.reward.minimum_contribution` when `amount` is actually `nil`? (Obviously I always expect amount to be numeric but I'm not sure how paranoid I should be in my validation / what exactly I can trust)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace `validates_each :amount` with:

```
...
validate :validate_mininum_amount

def validate_mininum_amount
  errors.add :amount, "some error message" if amount.to_i < reward.min_contribution
end
...
```

Note: Adding `.to_i` ensures that the amount will be `0` if it is `nil`. Or you could add a specific check for nil. Add any other checks you need to, in the `validate_mininum_amount` method.